# Find a simple path visiting all marked vertices

Tags: algorithms, graphs, reference-request, np-hard, hamiltonian-path

Let $G = (V, E)$ be a connected graph and let $M\subseteq V$. We say that a vertex $v$ is *marked* if $v\in M$.  The problem is to find a simple path in $G$ that visits the maximum possible number of marked vertices. The associated decision problem is: is there a simple path that visits every $v\in M$?

The problem is obviously more general than the problem of finding a Hamiltonian path in an arbitrary graph, so it is NP-hard.

I see no obvious strategy; one can't simply disregard the unmarked vertices, since they (and their incident edges) may be part of the optimal path.  Indeed, omitting them may disconnect the graph completely.

My questions:

1. Does this problem have a well-known name?
2. Are there any good approximation algorithms, heuristics, or simple reductions to problems I might know more about?
3. Where can I find this problem discussed in the literature?

Comment: Have removed tag discussion; see [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/188/renaming-tag-graphs-to-graph-theory) or a maybe upcoming new question on [meta].

Answer (score 3):

This problem is close to [Steiner tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_tree_problem) problem, just by two restriction:

1. Instead of tree we have path.
2. Is not necessary to have shortest path which contains required node.

There is a [recent work](http://dx.doi.org/10.5120/13242-0692)<sup>1</sup> on similar topic, the only difference with your problem statement is they are looking for shortest path which contains all required vertices. They name it Steiner Path problem.

<sub>1:
Shanti Swaroop Moharana, Ankit Joshi, and Swapnil Vijay. [Steiner path
for trees](http://www.ijcaonline.org/archives/volume76/number5/13242-0692). International Journal of Computer Applications, August
2013. Published by Foundation of Computer Science, New York, USA. ([doi](http://dx.doi.org/10.5120/13242-0692))</sub>

Comment: That paper seems to be only considering steiner paths on trees, not on general connected graphs, as the OP specified.

Answer (score 2):

The nearest neighbor method is often used as a heuristic for different problems. Sometimes the method gives an effective approximation algorithm as well. You could employ it here as well. Here's a skeleton for a heuristic method that maintains a stack $S$ of vertices representing the resulting simple path. Let $F$ be a set containing forbidden vertices, that is, vertices that have already been used in our final path. $F$ should be a data structure supporting fast insertion and lookup, such as a hash table or even a bitvector.

1. Pick a start node $s_0 \in M$ and let $S := \{s_0\}$, and $F = \emptyset$.
2. Choose a successor $s_i$ to $\text{top}(S)$, and try to find a path $s_{i-1} \leadsto s_i$ avoiding vertices in $F$. If a path is found, insert the vertices on the path $s_{i-1} \leadsto s_i$ to $F$.
3. Repeat step 2 until no successor can be found

For a more concrete implementation, consider the following:

1. Let $\text{Per}_M(G)$ be the *marked periphery*, that is, the marked vertices with highest eccentricity. Pick the start node $s_0$ such that $s_0 \in \text{Per}_M(G)$.
2. Using BFS, find the closest vertex to $\text{top}(S)$, where $S$ is the stack maintaining the path. Push the successor to the stack $S$. If a vertex $v$ is forbidden, i.e. $v \in F$, then the BFS won't visit it.
3. Repeat step 2 until no successor can be found.

I'll argue for the concrete implementation above:

1. You can think of picking the start vertex $s_0$ from the "convex hull" of $M$. Roughly, the idea is that you only need to expand the path into one direction, thus maximizing the "freedom of movement".
2. BFS seems like the simplest idea; alternatively one could experiment with other search methods, such as bidirectional search or randomized DFS. A randomized DFS might be a bad choice when there's only a few elements in $F$, then it's possible it'll produce very long paths between two marked vertices. On the other hand, running a randomized DFS -based heuristic resembles the idea of random restarts, which has been *very* effective in say SAT/CSP solvers or local search methods.

If you are able to find any additional properties of your input graphs and/or $M$, it might very well help you in tuning this heuristic.